# What do these line numbers mean in this error?

Tags: c++, build, g++, clang++

When compiling some code, I get an error like:

> `endpointer.h:88:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token`

What does the `:88:24` mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first bit is the line, the other the column. You should read it like this:

In file endpointer.h at line 88 and column 24

Answer (score 4):

It's the line number and the column number in your code where the error occured. It means you forgot a character.